# How to create a linq using a dataset from excel and having statements called from methods?

Tags: c#

I want to be able to use a call method for the object in order run the data through that switch statement? How to I do this.

Here is the excel data sheet
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLmXZ.jpg

```html
string format1 = "{0, -15}{1, -15}{2, -15}";
string[] info = File.ReadAllLines(filename.csv);
var list = from eachrow in info
                          let data = eachrow.Split(',', ' ')
                          let id = data[0]
                          let object = data[1]
                          let price = data[2]
                          orderby id
                          select new {id, object, price};
            foreach (var record in list)
            {
                listbox.Items.Add(string.Format(format1, record.id, record.object,record.price));
            }

{
private string object(ref string obj)
        {

            string objname = "";
            switch (obj)
            {
                case "t":
                    {
                        objectname = "Toy";
                        break;
                    }
                case "m":
                    {
                        objectname = "Mat";
                        break;
                    }
                case "l":
                    {
                        objectname = "lunch";
                        break;
                    }
            }
            return objectname;
}
```

Comment: Meant to say the switch statement*

Answer (score 0):

The problem looks like you are never calling your object() method. This should do the trick although it does not use free form Linq:

```
public static void Main(){
    var info = File.ReadAllLines(filename.csv);
    rows.Select(x => {
                var data = x.Split(',');
                return new {id = data[0], name = GetName(data[1]), price = data[2]};
            })
    .OrderBy(x => x.id)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(x => listbox.Items.Add(string.Format(format1, x.id, x.name, x.price)));
}

public static string GetName(string type)
{
    switch(type)
    {
        case "t":
            return "Toy";
        case "m":
            return "Mat";
        case "l":
            return "lunch";
        default:
            throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```